# fadeIn effect for HTML files using jQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble trying to add a fade effect when I click onto a link. It links to another HTML file that I have for this project.  Is it possible to fade in window.location using fadeIn()?

Here's my code:

```
$("button1").on("click", function() {
    window.location.replace("index2.html");
});

$(".button2").on("click", function () {
    window.location.replace("index3.html");
});

$(".button3").on("click", function () {
    window.location.replace("index1.html");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
$("button1").on("click", function() {
    $("body").fadeOut(1000,function(){
           window.location.href = "index2.html"
    })
});
```

Number 1000 represents the number of milliseconds that you want the fade out effect to last

And, add this to the page you're loading to get the fade in effect when the document is ready (for example in index2.html:

```
$(function(){
        $("body").hide();
        $("body").fadeIn(1000);
})
```